# How to check if args[0] is a normal String and not a non-existing file?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that expects an argument which can be both a file and a normal String argument. If it is a file, then I want to read the content of the file, if it is a String, I want to read the String.

The only idea I came up with is doing something like:

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
```

and then checking whether `if ( !file.isDirectory() || !file.isFile() )` and if that's the case, treating `args[0]` as a String. But if `args[0]` is a non existing file, like C:/Users/Name/Desktop/nonexistingFile.txt, it treats this argument like a String: "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/nonexistingFile.txt" to work with instead of saying "it's a non existing file".

How to check if `args[0]` is a normal String and not a non existing file?

Comment: is args an array of objects??

Comment: Have you considered just passing wether it is a file or a normal string as a parameter? So that you would call the programm with something like  "-file: /etc/lala" or "-string: blabla"

Comment: Without adding more information on the command line, e.g. whether it's meant to be a file or a string all you can do is guess: if the string looks like a file name (e.g. there is a path or an extension) you could assume it is a file - you can't be sure though (e.g. what if the user wants to read a file right next to the application and that file has no extension but then the user mistypes the file name?).

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  That's most likely the String array in `main`, like the name and question indicate.

Comment: @Tom so you are assuming that ***args*** mean the ***String[]*** from the main method? why?, where is OP saying that??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ *"I'm writing a program that expects an argument"* ...

Comment: @Tom and why do you mean that such a broad statement is implicitly and exclusively meaning the use of the main method? LoL

Comment: @Tom anyways... than for he useful comments!!!

Comment: Assuming these are arguments to `main()`, are you sure you want to do this? If `java MyProg foo` does something different depending on whether or not there's a file in the CWD called `foo`, isn't very user-friendly (unless the other behaviour is a message `file "foo" not found`). Much better to have flags e.g. `java MyProg --file foo`.

Answer (score 2):

If with `args` you are referring to the String array of your `main` method, then it is guaranteed to contains no `null` and every single element is a (proper) `String`.

However you would need to check whether `args` length is at least 1 as there is no guarantee that the user would had provided any argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (args.length <= 0) {
     // complain no argument was provided?
     return;
   }
   final String myFileName = args[0];
   final File myFile = new File(myFileName);
   if (!myFile.exists()) {
     // complain is not an existing file
   } else if (myFile.isFile()) {
     // handle the case the input file is a regular file.
   } else if (myFile.isDirectory()) {
     // handle the case the input file is in fact a directory
   } else {
     // complain is neither.
     // some operating system may contain other types of devices that are neither
     // files nor directories. so you should deal with such cases gracefully.
   }
}
```

However, since in practice some other piece of code may call that `main` method, not just the VM's start-up code perhaps you wanna do the actual check that `args` is in fact not null nor does it contain `null` (at least not in `args[0]`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (args == null) {
     // complain about this unexpected input (return or throw NPE, IAE???)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // in this case IAE.
   } else if (args.length <= 0) {
     // complain no argument was provided?
     return;
   } else if (args[0] == null) {
     // complain about this unexpected input (return or throw NPE, IAE???)
     throw new NullPointerException(); // in this case NPE.
   }
   ...
```